# Users with most profile views

Tags: support, statistics, profile-page

In our profile under the stats category, we can see our "**profile views**". I'm curious to know, Is there any options in SE sites to view the users according to their **profile views**, and sort them by profile views?

Comment: Are there still unclarities about the existing answers that you might want to adress in a comment?

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of this page there is a horizontal menu list that include the word *data*, which accesses the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Apparently, once the Movie & TV site is out of beta, you will be able to input SQL queries to run custom reports. There are a number of stored queries people have done for other SE sites that you can look at.

Comment: Can anyone run the SQL queries once we are out of beta? Or do you have to be above a certain rep?

Comment: @PriestVallon I'm pretty sure anyone as all the data here is CC licensed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this using the site directly. What you can do, though, is employing the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](http://data.stackexchange.com/), which provides a public interface to SE's internal data bases (well, not exactly all the internal data, but a subset in restructured form).

A query to list all users sorted by profile views could then be as easy as [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/376049):

```
SELECT Id AS [User Link], Views FROM Users ORDER BY Views DESC
```

Keep in mind, though, that the data explorer isn't updated in realtime but only once a week (usually sunday morning UTC), as written in [its help section](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).